# Implement a JS button - How to copy just the code and not the comment

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone and happy new year.

I do have a question regarding how to implement a little (I think not sure) JavaScript in order to copy the code inside a box, so user can directly paste into their shell.

The problem is that, the code inside the box comes from the MySQL DataBase, contains comments/descriptions/paragraphs/regular text.

You will understand what I am trying to say, please the example below:

Example, look at the command line from my website: http://www.clihelp.org/WI00261/see-the-status-of-the-w32time-service

As you can see from the page, the text inside the box titled Command Line Script could be easy to implement a JavaScript to copy the code and than paste.

But what about Example 1, Example 2, Example 3….

How can I tell the JavaScript to copy just the code and not the comments/text?

Again, look at the same issue.  This is another example:

http://www.clihelp.org/LX00050/sort

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Take the comment out of your code tag and then target the code tag would be my first idea

Comment: Each `<code>` tag in the page has the comment first, then `<br><br>` and then the command. A pretty easy workaround can be getting the content of `<code>`, splitting the `<br>` and getting the last element of the splitted string. If the `<br>` repetition (or \n) is consistent in each example you can adopt this strategy pretty conveniently.

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 1):

With something like [ClipboardJS](https://clipboardjs.com/) you can specify exactly what to copy and from where. You will need to provide a bit of extra markup to target the relevant bit. In this case I wrapped it into a `span`. An example from their docs, tweaked for your case:

```
<!-- Target -->
<code>
    Output a list of privileges
    <br>
    <br>
    <span id="command">sc qprivs w32time</span>
</code>

<!-- Trigger -->
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#command">
    <img src="assets/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
```